# Getting an annotation's field in Java

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

This is in annotation processing.
I have a TypeElement about which I know that it is annotated with @Bind.
I get the TypeElement with:

```
ProcessingEnvironment#getElementsAnnotatedWith(Bind.class)
```

@Bind looks like this:

```
public @interface Bind {
    Class<? extends Stuff>[] stuffArray();
}
```

I can do this:

```
typeElement.getAnnotation(Bind.class);
```

But I cannot do this, as it results in an MirroredTypesException:

```
typeElement.getAnnotation(Bind.class).stuffArray();
```

How do I get that array?

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The full stack trace is about 30 stack long, of which 29 is called by the javac, no point in posting it.